# Show 2 object data in single row in listview in Android

Tags: android, listview

I have a requirement as shown in this image.

[image]

I have 2 show 2 object data on single row. Normally we show these information as one object in one row. How could we achieve it.

Comment: can you pls explain a bit more..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use,

1. GridView
2. RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it customizing getView() method in listview adapter.
what getView() method do?

> getView() normally generates view for each row in a general sense.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    
    //inside this we populate data using position value
}
```

Here you need to show two object (sequence or random) data in a single row. You need to use another int variable to keep track about object size.

initialize it on top, `int i = 0;`

inside getView() you need to do something extra because you need to populate 2 object data on a single getView() method call.

1. Create 2 object and populate data using *i*.
2. increment *i* value after every object creation.
3. Put an **if** condition do check *i* value is less than your array size. Its because getView() method will call based on your array size and you need to populate data half / less of that.

****Populate data inside above **if** condition.

#### *Better you try [Gridview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) for this type of needs.

*Custom layout GridView [example](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Grid_Layout_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=76)

Answer (score 0):

You need ListView xml, ListItem xml, ListItem class (object), ArrayAdaper class

Set a row view and items in that view in ListItem xml. 
Create ListItem class (object) with variables (Such as String, int) you needed.
Bind the view and item in ArrayAdapter class.